# Complex integral with conjugate

Tags: complex-analysis

Is there any method of calculating an integral
$\int_{\Gamma}\frac{\overline{f(z)}}{z-z_0}dz$ where $f(z)$ is a holomorfic function.

Comment: What is $\Gamma$ ?

Comment: smooth closed curve

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is:
$$\int_{\Gamma}\frac{\overline{f(z)}}{z-z_0}dz=\int_a^b\frac{\overline{f(\Gamma(t))}}{\Gamma(t)-z_0}\Gamma'(t)dt=\int_a^b\overline{\left(\frac{f(\Gamma(t))}{\overline{\Gamma(t)}-\overline{z_0}}\overline{\Gamma'(t)}\right)}dt=\overline{\int_a^b\frac{f(\Gamma(t))}{\overline{\Gamma(t)}-\overline{z_0}}\overline{\Gamma'(t)}dt}$$
Since the variable of integration is real.

Comment: I think the formula you applied can be used to evaluate every complex integral with any continuous $f(z)$. The problem is that the last integral is usually very complicated or impossible to calculate. Is there the way of changing the smooth closed curve $\Gamma$ into another given curve?

Comment: Indeed - but there is no general way to do this. In some cases, the last integral can be represented as an integral of some other function on another smooth closed curve, but for that you need to know $\Gamma$ and $f$.